# Ref is strangely turning null in React

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I am trying to make a component slidable with the mouse. But when releasing the mouse, the reference on one of the DOM element is becoming null during the execution and I don't understand why.

I created a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-http-khjj0?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the problem.
(this is not the full implementation. Just what is needed to experiment the problem).

Just drag the elements and check the console. You will see that the ref is initially set correctly, but when releasing the mouse, the ref is gone.

I don't understand when this is happening and why.

Here is the full App.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const Slides = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
`;

const Slide = styled.div`
  width: ${props => props.size}%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
`;

const Carrousel = ({
  children,
  columnCount = 1,
  onSlideChanged = () => {},
  active = 0
}) => {
  const [dragging, setDragging] = React.useState(false);
  const initialMouseX = React.useRef(0); // Starting drag x coordinates
  const initialLeft = React.useRef(0); // Left value when the drag started
  const currentLeft = React.useRef(-active * (100 / children.length)); // Current left value
  const sliderRef = React.createRef();
  const slidesRef = React.createRef();

  // This will directly manipulate the DOM for better performances
  const setLeft = React.useCallback(
    newLeft => {
      currentLeft.current = newLeft;
      if (!slidesRef.current) return;
      slidesRef.current.style.left = currentLeft.current + "%";
    },
    [currentLeft, slidesRef]
  );

  // Starts the drag
  const startDrag = ({ screenX }) => {
    setDragging(true);
    initialMouseX.current = screenX;
    initialLeft.current = currentLeft.current;
  };
  // We need the references to be updated before being able to listen to move and mouseup events
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!dragging) return;
    console.log("at last render, slidesRef was:", slidesRef.current);
    const move = event => {
      if (dragging && sliderRef.current) {
        const width = sliderRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        const newLeft =
          initialLeft.current +
          ((event.screenX - initialMouseX.current) * 100) / width;
        setLeft(newLeft);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };
    const stopDrag = () => {
      setDragging(false);
      console.log("when calling stopDrag, slidesRef was:", slidesRef.current);
    };
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag);
    };
  }, [initialLeft, dragging, sliderRef, setLeft, slidesRef]);

  return (
    <Container ref={sliderRef}>
      <Slides ref={slidesRef} onMouseDown={startDrag}>
        {children.map((child, index) => (
          <Slide key={index} size={100 / columnCount}>
            {child}
          </Slide>
        ))}
      </Slides>
    </Container>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <Carrousel columnCount={2}>
    {new Array(4).fill("").map((_, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <span>Test{i + 1}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </Carrousel>
);

export default App;
```

The issue is within this part:

```js
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!dragging) return;
    console.log("at last render, slidesRef was:", slidesRef.current);
    const move = event => {
      if (dragging && sliderRef.current) {
        const width = sliderRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        const newLeft =
          initialLeft.current +
          ((event.screenX - initialMouseX.current) * 100) / width;
        setLeft(newLeft);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };
    const stopDrag = () => {
      setDragging(false);
      console.log("when calling stopDrag, slidesRef was:", slidesRef.current);
    };
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag);
    };
  }, [initialLeft, dragging, sliderRef, setLeft, slidesRef]);
```

When dragging, you will get: `at last render, slidesRef was: <div ...>`
and then when releasing: `when calling stopDrag, slidesRef was: null`

Comment: please clarify what you're looking for here. You're not logging anything to the _console_ in your sandbox and I can drag the carousel with no apparent issues.

Comment: I fixed it. I apparently don't know how to use codesandbox... Sorry for the misunderstanding and unclear instructions.